# After installing Magento 2.0.2 is very slow in loading home/admin page

Tags: magento-2.0

I installed magento 2.0.2 on WAMP 2.5 successfully but I see home/admin page takes at least 3-4 mins to get loaded and the case is same in page navigation. Kindly help me in getting my pages loaded faster . Below are my env details

OS:Windows 7 64 bit
WAMP:2.5
RAM:8GB

Early helps are appreciated .

Thanks
Kotresh NM

Comment: Are you running development, default or production mode?

Comment: I use a Virtual Machine of Lubuntu; a Lightweight Linux OS - Good for developing on through Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use WAMP
2. Do not use Windows

Use the Magento Dev Box:
<s>http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html</s>

Follow this guide:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/optimal-dev-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the folowing:

1. set production mode with gitbash cli in the magento root->bin folder : php magento deploy:mode:set production
2. set static content files: php magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. set di compile: php magento setup:di:compile
4. After doing the above go to magento admin and "Flush Magento Cache"
5. If you change any code(xml, phtml or css)
   a. go to magento root->var and delete folder "view_preprocessed"
   b. go to magento root->pub->static and delete all files and folder except .htaccess